# input type number hide arrows from right part of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 inputs with type number:

```
<input type="number">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkadr55g/1/

I want to hide arrows from the right for first input, 
I found solution using this code:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
     margin: 0; 
}
```

but if using this, all inputs doesn't create arrows

http://jsfiddle.net/dkadr55g/2/

how to set for first withoud arrows and for second with arrows?

Comment: now a days you can use <input inputmode="numeric" ..

reference : https://youtu.be/alGcULGtiv8?t=630

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add some class to distinguish inputs:

```css
 input[type=number].no-spinner::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
     margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
First number: <input type="number" class="no-spinner"><br>
Second number: <input type="number"><br>
```

Comment: input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

Comment: Good one! Here is it, indented with demo for [Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494158/1248177)

Answer (score 7):

Most answers are WebKit oriented. Here is a solution for most browsers, including Firefox.

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Firefox */
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" />
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

Answer (score 3):

you can simply add a class to your input

```
Second number: <input class="without_number" type="number"><br>
```

Than you select only fields with this class:

```
input[type=number].without_number::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number].without_number::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
     margin: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `class` attribute on your `input` elements and than in css file:
http://jsfiddle.net/weujr6us/

Answer (score 2):

try with `:first-of-type` Selects every `<input>` element that is the first `<input>` element of its parent

```
    input[type=number]:first-of-type::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    input[type=number]:first-of-type::-webkit-outer-spin-button{ 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
     margin: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple solution : Just add some `id` for First Input like `<input type="number" id="FirstInput">`

And update your css like :

```
#FirstInput::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    #FirstInput::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
     margin: 0; 
}
```

[**JsFiddle** example](http://jsfiddle.net/dkadr55g/4/)

Or add `class` for First Input as other answerers suggest.